# Node hierarchy messed up in Godot4 scene after reopening, how to revert back?

Tags: godot, godot4

Nodes all moved out of it's parent node and into the top parent?

Godot4

I just reopened the scene and found it like this. Was curious if I accidentally pressed something.
If it's a bug, only thing I can account to creating it would have been loading up an older project build or maybe using vscode with it?

Annoying but should be easy enough to move everything back because they seem to be named correctly.
[image: all nodes in parent node]

Comment: First time I see this. I think this could be relatively easy to fix by editing the scene file with a text editor. I have no idea how it happened... Unless you were, well, editing the file scene with a text editor. If you can manage to reproduce it, please take it to github: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues